# Kinetic sand simulation

Tags: unity, physics, simulations

I want to simulate [Kinetic sand's](https://giphy.com/gifs/kinetic-sand-r7ajNuIfiQ8dq) behavior in my game. I could implement operations such as slicing and cutting using simple mesh cutting algorithms but I want to implement complicated operations such as follows:

Ref video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3clqk2U3T9Y

1. Squishing (Time frame 1:37 to 1:40 in the ref video)
2. Scooping (Time frame 8:53 to 8:57 in the ref video)

I have the following questions:

1. What physics simulation algorithms can be used to implement the above 2 operations?
2. I want to implement this concept for mobile devices. Will it be computationally heavy to simulate such physics on mobile devices? if yes, are there any workaround solutions for this type of simulations?

I would appreciate any suggestions and thoughts on this topic. Thank you.

Comment: This is likely to be very computationally intensive to do well. Is there anything in your game mechanics we can use to simplify the problem? Say, if only certain squish / scoop angles are allowed, on preset shapes, we might be able to bake animations that work for those exact cases, without simulating and rendering thousands of grains of sand or advection of fluid pressure through thousands of cells every frame.

Comment: Thank you @DMGregory for the suggestion. I thought of that approach where we fake the simulations using animations but I am looking for a more robust solution.

Comment: Anything else you can tell us about your application that would let us simply the problem space from full general simulation? I'm not confident that you can achieve something with the fidelity and performance you want on mobile without some extra constraints or simplifications.

Comment: Thank you @DMGregory for the quick response. I have similar concerns about fidelity and performance on mobile. This game is in the initial stages of development and the design is not complete. Let me check with the design team if I could simply the problem space.